# How to pull image name from state for file pond

Tags: reactjs, filepond

When I navigate to a particular page I want the file pond image to be repopulated with an image I have already uploaded and the image name is in the database.

Currently I have the image name hardcoded, The image name is available in the state which is set in componentDidMount but the state is being set for file pond as well which is confusing me a bit to be honest.

So, this is when it is hardcoded:

```
class HomeBannerForm extends InputForm {
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: hero } = await getHero();
    this.setState({ data: this.mapToViewModel(hero) });
  }

      state = {
        data: {
          title: "",
          bgImg: ""
        },
        errors: {},
        files: [
          {
            source: "myImage.jpg",
            options: {
              type: "local"
            }
          }
        ]
      };

  mapToViewModel(hero) {
    return {
      id: hero._id,
      title: hero.title,
      bgImg: hero.bgImg
    };
  }
```

So, I need to change the myImage.jpg to what is in the state from componentDidMount ie: the name from the database. This obviously does not work.

```
    files: [
      {
        source: this.state.data.bgImg
        options: {
          type: "local"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Filepond component code:

```
            <FilePond
              ref={ref => (this.pond = ref)}
              files={this.state.files}
              allowMultiple={false}
              maxFiles={1}
              instantUpload={false}
              name="bgImg"
              server={{
                process: "http://localhost:8000/api/hero/",
                load: "http://localhost:8000/img/"
              }}
              oninit={() => this.handleInit()}
              onupdatefiles={fileItems => {
                // Set currently active file objects to this.state
                this.setState({
                  files: fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file)
                });
              }}
              // callback for successfully uploaded image
              onprocessfile={() => this.uploadComplete()}
            />
```

Comment: what are you doing with the file source? Is it being used as part of your render()?

Comment: That code is what renders the image on the screen through file pond. I don't actually have to call it in the render method. Will update my question with the file pond component code..

Comment: In case this helps: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/frameworks/react/

Comment: so filepond helps you drag and drop files for upload, right? just so I understand, are you trying to load a single item in to the filepond filelist (like a default or demo item) when the page loads?

Comment: Correct, it's a file uploader. I have uploaded an image and I can see it on the server and the file name is in the database. When I close my browser and go back to that page, it should show me the image I uploaded previously as that is the record in the database. Think of my use case as when you want to go and change your profile pic for example

Comment: I found this section in the docs for preloading images but it isn't clear, well to me anyway, on how to do it with file names from the database / dynamic names. https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-object/#setting-initial-files

Comment: So...  just so I understand, do you want the previously-uploaded file to be shown in filepond or not?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be shown

Comment: I want the last file I uploaded and saved to be preloaded in file pond when I go back to that page, in the same way that the title will be there which is also pulling from the database, except the title would be in a text input field and the image will be in the file pond instance. I am essentially just editing an existing database record

Comment: and what happens at the moment?

Comment: If I upload a new image it stores the image in an img directory on my node server and the database record is updated to reflect the new file name. That is working all fine. The issue is that when I go back to the page it is still showing myImg.jpg because that is what I have hardcoded in there. I don't know how to set it from the state since it is being declared when setting the state.

Comment: Look at my original question where `myImage.jpg` is. That needs to be from the state ie: `this.state.data.bgImg`

Comment: When you call `getHero()` method, all you want is to assign `bgImg` (file name coming from DB) property directly to `files[{source: bgImg}]`? Will this solve the matter?

Comment: That sounds like it could work yes, not sure how to do that though

Comment: If I replace `source:myImg.jpg` with `source:bgImg` then I get an error that bgImg is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to tweak your hero mapping:

```
mapToState(hero) {
   return {
     data: {
       title: hero.title,
       bgImg: hero.bgImg
     },
     errors: {},
     files: [
       {
         source: hero.bgImg,
         options: {
           type: "local"
        }
      }
    ]
  };
}
async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: hero } = await getHero();
    this.setState(this.mapToState(hero));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but still get the error that bgImg is not defined when using `source: bgImg`

Comment: Hang on, you have changed the code again. This seemed like it was working `async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: hero } = await getHero();
    this.setState({
      files: [{ id: hero._id, title: hero.title, source: hero.bgImg }]
    });
  }` Should I rather use your new edit?

Comment: sorry, I updated it to more closely reflect your existing code... the other one just moved the mapToViewModel in-line

Comment: Hmm, now with your new change I get 'mapToViewModel' is not defined'

Comment: Ah, just missing THIS ie: this.mapToViewModel I think

Comment: lol. well, I updated it to inline so it works anyway (been working with functional components a lot yesterday so hardly use 'this' any more!)

Comment: I'll leave it to you to finesse it :-D

Comment: You have changed the name from bgImg to source though. I am assuming I will need to go to my node backend and change that then?

Comment: no, the mapping takes care of that. filepond needs the file to be called `source` - that's where the problem was. You can call it what you like in your BE.

Comment: Aaaaannndd. The text that was in my text field is now gone. I am guessing because you changed my state which has removed the data object I had

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197581/discussion-between-will-jenkins-and-user8463989).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class HomeBannerForm extends InputForm {

state = {
        data: {
          title: "",
          bgImg: ""
        },
        errors: {},
        files: [
          {
            source: "myImage.jpg",
            options: {
              type: "local"
            }
          }
        ]
      };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: hero} = await getHero();
this.setState(prevState => ({
      data: this.mapToViewModel(hero),
      files: prevState.files.map(obj => {
        Object.assign(obj, { source: hero.bgImg });
      })
    }));

  }



  mapToViewModel(hero) {
    return {
      id: hero._id,
      title: hero.title,
      bgImg: hero.bgImg
    };
  }
```